# Javascript Validation of both Checkboxes and Radio Buttons

Tags: javascript, validation, checkbox

I am doing a checklist that needs to be completed each time a member of staff completes this particular form. Please note that I am still grasping JS slowly due to not having a large amount of time to research.

I have done a bit of research and combined some different validation styles and come up with this;

```
function validate(form) {
    var e = form.elements;

    if(e['reloaded'].value == "yes") {
        if(!e['Q1-A'].value) {
            alert('You Must complete the Checklist!');
            return false;
        }
        if(!e['Q1-B'].value) {
            alert('You Must complete the Checklist!');
            return false;
        }
        if(!e['Q1-C'].value) {
            alert('You Must complete the Checklist!');
            return false;
        }
        if(!e['Q1-D'].value) {
            alert('You Must complete the Checklist!');
            return false;
        }
        if(!e['Q1-E'].value) {
            alert('You Must complete the Checklist!');
            return false;
        }
        if(!e['Q1-G'].value) {
            alert('You Must complete the Checklist!');
            return false;
        }
        if(!e['Gen-A'].value) {
            alert('You Must complete the Checklist!');
            return false;
        }
        if(!e['Gen-B'].value) {
            alert('You Must complete the Checklist!');
            return false;
        }
        if(!e['invoice_number'].value) {
            alert('Invoice Number is REQUIRED!');
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    } else if(e['reloaded'].value == "no") {
        if(!e['Gen-A'].value) {
            alert('You Must complete the Checklist!');
            return false;
        }
        if(!e['Gen-B'].value) {
            alert('You Must complete the Checklist!');
            return false;
        }
        if(!e['Q2-A'].value) {
            alert('You Must complete the Checklist!');
            return false;
        }
        if(!e['invoice_number'].value) {
            alert('Invoice Number is REQUIRED!');
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    } else if(!e['reloaded'].value) {
        alert('You must indicate if you Reloaded the OS!');
        return false;
    }
}
```

At this stage it is simply returning "You must indicate if you Reloaded the OS!" even when it is selected.

The point is to select an option from a radiobutton selection, then it will show some checkboxes and all checkboxes must be checked before the form can be submitted. Obviously some checkboxes only show if a particular option is selected and as such some need to be excluded from being required.
There is also an additional field that needs to be filled (invoice_number) which has always had validation on it and has always worked.

The Radio Buttons:

```
<input name="reloaded" id="reloaded" type="radio" value="yes" onClick="Q1(this.value);" /> Yes</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <label><input name="reloaded" id="reloaded" type="radio" value="no" onClick="Q1(this.value);" />
```

The Checkboxes are all the same except the ID's/Names

```
<input name="Q1-A" id="Q1-A" type="checkbox" value="yes" />
```

Required Text Box:

```
<input class="field size5" type="text" name="invoice_number" id="invoice_number" placeholder="Required! - 'RA' for Warranty Jobs" />
```

I am sure that I have over complicated it due to my lack of knowledge, however I just cannot think of where i have gone wrong.

(Submission is occurring via `onsubmit="return validate(this);"`)

Comment: show the complete html

Comment: I have updated to show the input html, Q1 function simply shows and hides divs with the checkboxes in them.

Comment: Yes I have already used the jQuery library with a few premade scripts with this project, so it shouldnt conflict with anything. I tried to use JS so I could write most of it and learn as I went haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code was my final result and it works;

```
                function validate(form) {
                var e = form.elements;

              if(document.getElementById('RL-Y').checked) {
                  if(!e['Q1-A'].checked || !e['Q1-B'].checked || !e['Q1-C'].checked || !e['Q1-D'].checked || !e['Q1-E'].checked || !e['Q1-G'].checked || !e['Gen-A'].checked || !e['Gen-B'].checked) {
                    alert('You Must complete the Checklist!');
                    return false;
                  }
                  if(!e['invoice_number'].value) {
                    alert('Invoice Number is REQUIRED!');
                    return false;
                  }
                  return true;

              } else if(document.getElementById('RL-N').checked) {
                  if(!e['Gen-A'].checked || !e['Gen-B'].checked || !e['Q2-A'].checked) {
                    alert('You Must complete the Checklist!');
                    return false;
                  }
                  if(!e['invoice_number'].value) {
                    alert('Invoice Number is REQUIRED!');
                    return false;
                  }
                  return true;

              } else {
                alert('You must indicate if you Reloaded the OS!');
                return false;
              }
            }
```